# Is there a better way to save and retrieve data between object and database?

Tags: .net

I have been writing many .NET applications in which SQL Server is involved.

For each database table, I wrote a corresponding class in .NET.

Example:

```
Class A
{
    property a;
}
```

Then I have to write another class to do with the class A for saving and retrieving from the database:

```
Class AdB
{
    public A parse(Datatable objectA){} // for parsing objectA from db to A

    public void add(A a){}   // write query to add A into the database

    public void remove(A a) {} // write query to remove A from the database

    public void update(A a) {} // write query to update A into the database
}
```

As a result, I have to write for test cases for the methods: parse(), add(), remove() and update()

Is there is a recent technology to make it simpler of saving and retrieving from and into database?

Comment: Evaluate both NHibernate (use Fluent NHibernate if you despise XML) and Entity Framework. They are very good ORMs. Learn Entity Framework after you learned NHibernate

Comment: Just Nuget both ORM's latest versions and see for yourself which fits your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) is that what you need?

Comment: Maybe NHibenate is what he need? ;-)

Comment: There is not big defference, but EF is going with Farmework and NHibernate must be installed separately

Comment: If we go by that logic, we should be using Sql Server only, as SqlDataClient is built right into the framework, no need for it to be installed separately. So I don't buy that as a good enough reason to learn EF(just because it is bundled) and ignore other sound ORMs